# Correct way to use Polymer 2 elements in Polymer 3 element?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

How can I use Polymer 2 elements in Polymer 3 element?  The following doesn't work since `<link>` element doesn't work inside shadow dom.

```
static get template() {
    return '
        <link rel="import" href="...">
        <my-element></my-element>';
}
```

We can simply take out `<link>` outside of the element and put at the top level, but that feels like breaking component-ness.

Comment: I think it's impossible to combine elements of Polymer 2 with Polymer 3

Answer (score 1):

You can't load two version of Polymer (Polymer 2/1 and Polymer 3) because Polymer register some custom-elements to the api of webcomponents and when you try to load a component from Polymer 2 and another of Polymer 3 it tells you that you can't register x custom-element again.

But you can use LitElement and a component from Polymer 2/1, you just have to use [html-import-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-import-js) inside your LitElement component.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a Polymer 2 component into a Polymer 3 component using this tool:
https://github.com/Polymer/tools/tree/master/packages/modulizer

Answer (score 0):

you seems to be looking for shared styles. Since polymer provides shadow DOM., scope is limited to component DOM. Better refer shared styles here... [click here](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom) and give ctrl+f., search for `Share styles between elements`